# How to update a jtable model

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have populated a JTable from file. After populating data into JTable i can edit the 
data but the changes i made to the data are not applied. I want the changes to be applied and later i want to save the updated data into file.

Below is the code to populate the table

```
ArrayList arrayList1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList arrayList  = new ArrayList();
reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream( mainpath ) ) );
Map<String, Object[]> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
boolean b = false;
int r1 = rcount - 1;
while( reader.ready() ) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if( count == 0 )
        count++;
    else {
        String[] values = line.split( "," );
        String vit = values[0];
        String amt = values[1];
        String rda = values[2];
        String brand = values[3];
        String product = values[4];
        int rcount1 = Integer.parseInt( values[5] );
        if( rcount1 == r1 ) {
            if( result.containsKey( vit ) ) {
                result.clear();
                result.put( vit, new Object[] { b, vit, amt, rda } );
                arrayList = new ArrayList( result.values() );
                for( Object v : arrayList ) {
                    arrayList1.add( v );
                }
            } else {
                if( arrayList.size() > 0 ) {
                    arrayList.clear();
                    result.clear();
                }
                result.put( vit, new Object[] { b, vit, amt, rda } );
                arrayList = new ArrayList( result.values() );
                for( Object v : arrayList ) {
                    arrayList1.add( v );
                }
            }
            combo.setSelectedItem( brand );
            combo1.setSelectedItem( product );
        }
    }
}
jTable3.setModel( new AnimalTableModel( arrayList1 ) );
```

First column is a checkbox,  second col a combobox, third col accepts floats,  fourth accepts integers.

Any suggestions would be really helpful....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please limit your code only to what is strictly necessary to understand your problem. And make sure to format it correctly as well

Comment: sorry.. will follow it definitely for next time ..

Comment: You could follow it this time! You can use the "edit" link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add an item...

```
jTable3.getModel().getWhateverFunctionGetsYourArray().add(item);
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. My problem is, the changes i made to jtable model after populating from file are not applied.I would like to change few values first and then try to save the corrected values to a file.

Answer (score 2):

```
jTable3.setModel(new AnimalTableModel(arrayList1));
```

seems to be wrong. This action sets a new model to your JTable, and what you do want is to update your existing model. If I wanted to assign a `ResultSet` to it for example, I'd code this:

```
tablemodel_foo = resultset_bar;
```

You don't need to access to your JTable since it's linked with its assigned model. Unless you you use the `GetModel` method as Rocky suggests.

Answer (score -2):

You can create your own JTable model, set new values then get the collection and iterates over it.
This is some model using **Java 7**

```
package com.java7;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class CustomerTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 281838548127943945L;
    private List<Customer> customers;

    public CustomerTableModel(int count) {
        createColumns();
        this.customers = new ArrayList<Customer>(count);
        Customer customer;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(i);
            customer.setName("Customer " + i);
            customer.setPhone("Phone of Customer " + i);
            customer.setEmail("Email of Customer " + i);
            insertRow(i, customer);
        }
    }

    public void insertRow(int row, Customer customer) {
        this.insertRow(row, customer.toArray());
        this.customers.add(row, customer);
    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return this.customers;
    }

    private void createColumns() {
        this.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[] { "id", "name", "phone", "email" });
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return super.getColumnName(col);
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Customer customer = customers.get(row);
        String columnIdentifer = super.getColumnName(col);
        switch (columnIdentifer) {
        case "id":
            return customer.getId();
        case "name":
            return customer.getName();
        case "phone":
            return customer.getPhone();
        case "email":
            return customer.getEmail();
        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        Customer customer = customers.get(row);
        String columnIdentifer = super.getColumnName(col);
        switch (columnIdentifer) {
        case "name":
            customer.setName((String) value);
            break;
        case "phone":
            customer.setPhone((String) value);
            break;
        case "email":
            customer.setEmail((String) value);
        default:
            break;
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        String columnIdentifer = super.getColumnName(c);
        switch (columnIdentifer) {
        case "id":
            return Integer.class;
        case "name":
            return String.class;
        case "phone":
            return String.class;
        case "email":
            return String.class;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (super.getColumnName(col).equals("id"))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

This is the Customer class:

```
package com.java7;

public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        Object[] data = new Object[4];
        data[0] = this.id;
        data[1] = this.name;
        data[2] = this.phone;
        data[3] = this.email;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for the very weird model implementation: a) dataChanged is the wrong event to fire on updates b) the state of the super's data vector is not kept in sync c) reason for b is the filling of super with customer data and later on forget about that filling ... If you have a bean-backed model, there is no reason to extend DefaultTableModel. Instead extend AbstractTableModel.